# Redis fails to open the RDB file due to read-only file system

Tags: redis

I run Redis as part of an app that I work on, but I never use it directly, so I'm not familiar with troubleshooting it. Today, it started throwing an error when quitting it using Ctrl+C, which used to work and still does on another machine.

The error is:

```
^C84445:signal-handler (1583959690) Received SIGINT scheduling shutdown...
84445:M 11 Mar 2020 16:48:10.750 # User requested shutdown...
84445:M 11 Mar 2020 16:48:10.750 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
84445:M 11 Mar 2020 16:48:10.750 # Failed opening the RDB file dump.rdb (in server root dir /) for saving: Read-only file system
84445:M 11 Mar 2020 16:48:10.750 # Error trying to save the DB, can't exit.
84445:M 11 Mar 2020 16:48:10.750 # SIGTERM received but errors trying to shut down the server, check the logs for more information
```

I'm running v5.0.5, which I installed through Homebrew. I start Redis using `redis-server`. I'm assuming this is due to macOS Catalina's security changes, but like I said, it works on another machine that also runs Catalina. How can I resolve this?

I'm able to shut it down if I run it with `redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis.conf`, but I never needed to use this before. What's the difference?